# Multiple markers at this line help me

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am getting the message multiple markers at this line:

```
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
 Expression
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 Statement
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
 ClassBody
```

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Menemukan lokasi tombol di activity_main.xml
        Button tombol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //Menangkap Klik pada Tombol
        tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent Intentku = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AktivitasBaru.class);
     startActivity(Intentku);

     } <<<<<<<<<< eror    

        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `);` after you error to complete this anonymous class declaration

Comment: This is Java not Javascript, tags revised

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your on click listener anonymous class properly, you should have:

```
tombol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Intent Intentku = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AktivitasBaru.class);
     startActivity(Intentku);
   }
});
```

You are missing the last line.

Comment: The nested type MainActivity cannot hide an enclosing type